# Discord music bot (Python)

Tags: python, heroku, discord, bots

It is discrod music bot, but why it doesn't work on heroku? In my pc allways working fine, but in heroku i have some problems with downloading android player API JSON. How can i fix it?

Alpication log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujptN.png)

Comment: Do not post the error message as an image: I recommend sharing it as a text so it can be tracked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.